# Coding this Auto Time Stamp script, it is only working in rows 6-30, never defined limited cell range?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, issue-tracking

> Followed a tutorial to create a script for time stamping and it works but only fills in from row 6-30 yet I never defined that in the script, really new to coding, and I have no clue why this script would have some odd range limit in it.

```
        function onEdit(e) {

  addTimestamp(e);

}


function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables
  var startRow = 3;
  var targetColumn = 13;
  var ws = "Refi";

  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === 10 && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws ){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).setValue(currentDate);
  } // END ID check column, row, worksheet

} // END function addTimestamp
```

Comment: Could you maybe expand in what you mean by `only fills in from row 6-30`. What are you expecting to happen with your script? I don't see anything wrong about your code, It will update the row being modified at column 13 when the cell you have modified is at column tenth and a higher row than 3. Try to explain exactly what you want so we can go ahead and help you.

Comment: It only prints the date to column 13 in cells 6-30, and even though I haven't touched a thing, I just got on and now it won't post the date in any cells.

Comment: It only prints the date to column 13 in cells 6-30, and even though I haven't touched a thing, I just got on and now it won't post the date in any cells. My goal is to have column 10 a notes column automatically create a time stamp in column 13 each time the cell gets edited. Ideally I need an example of code to exclude certain rows too as some rows are separators for organization and I don't want those to create I timestamp, for now I just protected those with the protect range option. Is that enough info, sorry not great at explaining this stuff I don't understand most of it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what to say about your problem, from my testing your code is working just fine in every row. Whenever I modify a row in `J` (10th column) it updates the column `M` (13th column).

About your other problem, is at easy as get the list of rows that you don't want to modify and use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if the list is not in the range.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  addTimestamp(e);
}

function addTimestamp(e){
  //variables
  var startRow = 3;
  var targetColumn = 13;
  var ws = "Refi";
  var protectedRows = [28, 49]; // Added variable

  //get modified row and column
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === 10 && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws
    && protectedRows.indexOf(row) == -1){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,13).setValue(currentDate);
  } // END ID check column, row, worksheet

} // END function addTimestamp
```

Of course to show you I have hardcoded the rows that I don't want to take action on. If that works for your case, great. If it does not, just change the way you get the row numbers, maybe is stored somewhere, or retrieved directly from the sheet.

In the end I got something like this:

[image: Result of sheet]